# Removing Punctuation and Replacing it with Whitespace using Replace in Python

Tags: python, replace, whitespace

trying to remove the following punctuation in python I need to use the replace methods to remove these punctuation characters and replace it with whitespace ,.:;'"-?!/

here is my code:

```
text_punct_removed = raw_text.replace(".", "")
text_punct_removed = raw_text.replace("!", "")
print("\ntext with punctuation characters removed:\n", text_punct_removed)
```

It only will remove the last one I try to replace, so I tried combining them

```
text_punct_removed = raw_text.replace(".", "" , "!", "")
print("\ntext with punctuation characters removed:\n", text_punct_removed)
```

but I get an error message, how do I remove multiple punctuation? Also there will be an issue if I put the " in quotes like this """ which will make a comment, is there a way around that?  thanks

Comment: raw_text is a text file it is referencing, It works if I do one like and remove commas but I need to remove all punctuation listed ,.:;'"-?!/

Comment: Please add the error message to here which you are getting.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to explicitly use replace:

```
exclude = set(",.:;'\"-?!/")
text = "".join([(ch if ch not in exclude else " ") for ch in text])
```

Comment: Optionally, combine this with (`import string`) `string.punctuation` and it works rather well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive but working solution:

```
for sp in '.,"':
    raw_text = raw_text.replace(sp, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to replace all punctuations with space, you can use the built-in punctuation list to replace the string:

**Python 3**

```
import string
import re

my_string = "(I hope...this works!)"

translator = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
translator.sub(' ', my_string)

print(my_string)
# Result:
#  I hope   this works
```

After, if you want to remove double spaces inside string, you can make:

```
my_string = re.sub(' +',' ', my_string).strip()

print(my_string)
# Result:
# I hope this works
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Python3.5.3:

```
from string import punctuation

raw_text_with_punctuations = "text, with: punctuation; characters? all over ,.:;'\"-?!/"
print(raw_text_with_punctuations)
for char in punctuation:
    raw_text_with_punctuations = raw_text_with_punctuations.replace(char, '')
print(raw_text_with_punctuations)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either remove one character at a time:

```
raw_text.replace(".", "").replace("!", "")
```

Or, better, use regular expressions (`re.sub()`):

```
re.sub(r"\.|!", "", raw_text)
```

Comment: thank you that worked!  how do I remove a quote?  cause it will be inside two quotes which makes it  comment """

Comment: I got it, use a single quote like this '"'